# Capture Keyboard Input retrieved from USB QR Code Scanner using Pynput

Tags: python, python-3.x, qr-code, barcode-scanner, keylistener

I have a USB QR Code scanner and it simulates the reading in of keyboard input.

It will output anything it reads to applications that can handle keyboard input (i.e. notepad)

I have a QR Code generator working where it creates a QR Code with the value of a random 20 char string.

I then scan the generated QR Code with my scanner to capture its value.

To capture its value, I am trying to create a listener using Python 3.5 and Pynput to append every simulated key press into a list.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

scannedInput = []

def on_press(key):
    scannedInput.append(key)


def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

with Listener(on_press=on_press,on_release=on_release) as listener: listener.join()


print(scannedInput)
```

The listener does capture and print the data to screen.

However I can't access the scannedInput list and the print statement at the end doesn't get called.

I need the scannedInput data to perform validations.

Any advice?

Edit:

My code has changed since this question was originally posted.

It now looks like so.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import time

scannedInput = []

def on_press(key):
    scannedInput.append(key)
    return True


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    while( time.sleep(5)):
        listener.join()
    Listener.stop(listener)

print(scannedInput)
```

Comment: I've never used `pynput` but I just had a quick look at the docs on PyPI & your code looks reasonable. Wild guess: Add `return True` to your `on_press` callback. It may make no difference, but it can't hurt to try it. :) It's a common convention that event handlers return `True` to indicate that they've handled the event and no further processing is required, and return `False` to indicate that the event should "bubble up" to the parent for (further) handling. Currently, `on_press` returns `None`, which is False-ish.

Comment: Thanks @PM2Ring I added the return True to on_press but still having the same issues. I know that scannedInput gets populated I just can't access it. Perhaps the Listener needs to be closed off?

Comment: Ah, right. Maybe `on_release` is the "culprit"... let me take a closer look at those docs. I assume that your scanner returns ESC to signal the end of data. Is that correct?

Comment: I use a javascript function to generate a HTML5 QR Code where its data is the random string but I don't have the escape key as the last value in the random string. Is that what you mean? Theoretically then if I put the escape key at the end of my random string when it is read in it will call the on_release??

Comment: I was assuming that you have the `Key.esc` stuff in there because your scanner is sending it. You shouldn't _need_ to have a special stop character in your data, and using a stop code would make it annoying to decode QRs that contain arbitrary binary data. But you do need to have _some_ way to tell the listener to stop listening.

Comment: I have removed the Key.esc  and I am going to try use the "Brutal" approach and see if that works.

Comment: One clunky solution is to pass a `timeout` arg to [`listener.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join). When the timeout expires, the Listener will stop. A more sophisticated way is to use a timer that sends the `Listener.stop` signal. Each time you receive a key, stop and re-start the timer, and if a key doesn't arrive within the desired time frame the signal from the timer stops the listener.

Comment: A simple but inefficient way is to just stop and restart the Listener for every key received. For others who wish to contribute, the pynput docs can be found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynput).

Comment: I will be honest anything that works will suffice for the moment as it is part of a proof of concept.

Comment: I have removed the `on_release` but I have no idea how to pass the timeout to the `listener.join()`. It gives me an error when I pass it to the `.join()`

Comment: That's weird. Since "keyboard listener is a threading.Thread" you should be able to do eg `listener.join(5.0)` to specify a 5 second timeout. Please paste the full traceback into your question, in a code block to preserve formatting.

Comment: I recently got it working with a timer and while loop which you will find above in the question. However I just realised I will need to be scanning things constantly so a timer with a window of X seconds won't suffice. I would need this to be always on and have it run anytime it receives input and stop X seconds after it gets the input. Is this possible?

Comment: It would probably be a Good Idea to read the docs for the threading module to learn what threads can do and how to use them.